# How is Flash For iphone Package gonna effect

Tags: iphone, flash

I'm an Objective C developer. The new announcement of the Flash for iphone got me
kinda worried. can some 1 explain how good is that package and if the need of objective C
developers/companies is gonna decrease ?? can you do really nice applications and games in
a much easyer way ? please advise me in that matter

Sincerely

Comment: Not really programming related. Also, please use proper english and punctuation if you expect people to take you seriously.

Comment: I'm truly sorry about the language, I'll try harder the next time.

Comment: Don't mind Bob's comment , you don't have to take him seriously either ;) he may be having a bad day!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693220/what-does-adobe-packager-mean-for-iphone-ipad-developers-closed